# Use Youtube Data API in React Native

Tags: react-native, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-data-api

is it possible to use Youtube Data API in a React Native application for Android?

With the Youtube Data API I want to retrieve my uploads of my channel ...

Comment: Hi. Maybe it will work.

https://github.com/indatawetrust/react-native-youtube-oauth/blob/master/demo/api/routes/index.js

Returns the video of the channel that is logged in with code.

Answer (score -2):

This appears to only allow you to play a video, not access the rest of the youtube api like search results